# iOS: How to make Gesture recognizer more responsive when animation is happening?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uigesturerecognizer

I have 4 subviews in a UIViewController page arranged as a grid. Sometimes, animations will be running on the subviews. I am trying to recognize taps on one of the subviews (using UITapGestureRecognizer).

Now, the when animation is not running, taps are recognized smoothly. But, when an animation is running, most of my taps are not recognized at all (even when animation is running on another subview).

Is there any way to increase priority of the Gesture recognizer than the animation ? Any  suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to setting animation options as 0. After adding `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` as the animation option, it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This *sounds like* a classic case of the main thread being clogged up. Multithreading will solve your problem.

**Do something like this:**

```
-(void)performAnimations{
    //Do your animations in this method
}
```

**Once you have your animations in a separate method, you're free to do this:**

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(performAnimations)];
```

This will leave your main thread free to recognize the touch events :)

Comment: I tried this, but, still getting the same effect - unresponsive while running the animation. Is there something to configure before multithreading works?

Comment: If you added an autorelease pool and your animations work fine with the new method structure, it might be time to look at cleaning up the animation code. In my experience iPod touch 2G and up can take pretty much any normal use case. I really can't think of anything more you could do to make the gesture recognition more responsive. Sorry.